# Native image with gluonfx fails if I use org.graalvm.nativeimage.c

Tags: javafx, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I have a JavaFx project that I am compiling to native with no problems using GluonFx.

I recently had to add a feature that uses a DLL through  to make use of its native functions. I have done this through GraalVm using this solution: https://yyhh.org/blog/2021/02/writing-c-code-in-javaclojure-graalvm-specific-programming/

Now when trying to compile to native with gluonfx:build I am getting the following error:

```
[Project source] package org.graalvm.nativeimage.c does not exist
[Project source] package org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.function does not exist
[Project source] package org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.function does not exist
[Project source] package org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.struct does not exist
[Project source] package org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.struct does not exist
[Project source] package org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.type does not exist
[Project source] package org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.type does not exist
[Project source] package org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.type does not exist
[Project source] package org.graalvm.word does not exist
[Project source] cannot find symbol symbol: class CContext
[Project source]cannot find symbol symbol: class CLibrary
.....
.....
```

Does someone had this issue before? Shouldn't graalvm.nativeimage.c be part of the graalvm sdk?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add the required dependencies (like `org.graalvm.nativeimage:library-support`) to the project?

Comment: Thanks a lot one more time, that solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by [José Pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956070/jos%C3%A9-pereda) in comments

"Did you add the required dependencies (like org.graalvm.nativeimage:library-support) to the project?"

Adding the dependency solved my problem. Thanks