# Get directory of compiled native image by GraalVM at runtime

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I compiled my Java application with (GluonFX which itself uses) GraalVM. **How can I get the directory where my application binary resides at runtime?** (not the users working directory)

- Before using GraalVMs native-image tool, I used to read `System.getProperty("java.home")` and deduced it from there. But this system property does not exist anymore.
- I tried to find another system property, but the directory of my application was in none.
- I tried to read environment variables and found `System.getenv("_")`, but as "_ contains the last program run", this does not feel stable.
- I tried to resolve `Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath()` but this only returned the current working directory.

My end goal is to package this small application binary in a bigger application and this small application should call other applications which will get packaged next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the running path from java code like below

```java
Path path = Path.of(
        Main.class.getProtectionDomain()
                .getCodeSource()
                .getLocation()
                .toURI()
).getParent();
System.out.println(path);
```

Please change the Main class to the class you use in your code.

There is another way too but that requires nativeimage dependency.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
    <artifactId>library-support</artifactId>
    <version>23.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

then call it like below

```java
System.out.println("exe path:"+ProcessProperties.getExecutableName());
```

example output

```bash
oz-mint@ozmint-MACH-WX9:~/Downloads/my-gluon-application$ ./target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/My\ Gluon\ Application 
exe path:/home/oz-mint/Downloads/my-gluon-application/target/gluonfx/x86_64-linux/My Gluon Application
Dec 30, 2023 3:22:52 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @71c7db30'
Dec 30, 2023 3:22:53 PM com.gluonhq.attach.util.Platform <clinit>
INFO: [Gluon Attach] System Property javafx.platform is not defined. Platform will be set to Platform.DESKTOP
```

working [example](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/java-examlpes/tree/master/graalvm-exe-path-finder)

References

- https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/4216
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71295418/175554

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that ozkanpakdils answer works. Meanwhile I found also another solution:

```
ProcessHandle.current().info().command()
```

This "returns the executable pathname of the process" (from its Javadoc).

I use it like this:

```
String appDirectory = ProcessHandle.current().info().command().map(Paths::get).orElseThrow().getParent().toAbsolutePath()
```